# My CPU frequency stays the same all the time, why?

Tags: cpu-speed

My CPU(FX9590) clock speed stays at 1.37 GHz all the time even while gaming, but my maximum frequency is able to reach 4.72 GHz at most.

I tried to change the clock speed through AI Suite II(I am using Asus Formula Z as my Mainboard) but it didn't help at all.

My energy scheme is on high performance and I never changed it, so it has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Just to make sure its not measurement error, can you confirm that your frequency is stuck in CPU-Z? http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html

Comment: I didn't install CPU-Z, but I think the frequency is stucking. Because clearly I felt something is not right while I play games. The lag within low setting just could not happen with my hardwares.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the turbo to work, all settings in your BIOS have to be set to auto, and the turbo feature has to be enabled.

If you have that enabled but it still is not getting this speed, it is likely that your cooling is not optimal, and it clocks down due to prevent overheating.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with cooling. I am using water cooling system. a

Comment: @McR3v3n5 I was just being thorough.